# javascript: Switching one pair of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Stackoverflow site, the voting arrow initially it can be "vote-up-off"/"vote-down-off" if a user hasn't voted. It can also be one up / another down if the user voted before. Start from this 3 cases, upon the user click, I want to switch class. With help of nice people on this site, I arrived this code so far:

```
if($("a.vote-up-down").hasClass("vote-up-on")){
    $(".vote-up-on").removeClass("vote-up-on").addClass("vote-up-off");
    $(".vote-down-off").removeClass("vote-down-off").addClass("vote-down-on");
}
else if($("a.vote-up-down").hasClass("vote-down-on")){
    $(".vote-down-on").removeClass("vote-down-on").addClass("vote-down-off");
    $(".vote-up-off").removeClass("vote-up-off").addClass("vote-up-on");
}
```

This works if you don't click up arrow again when it is already vote-up-on, or you don't click down arrow again when it is already vote-down-on. Otherwise, it keeps switching disregarding the actual vote. If initially both arrow is off, this code will change both. 
In my ajax function, I can provide response message of actual vote value ( 1 or -1), How can I correct the above code?

Comment: When do you execute this code? Inside an event handler?

Comment: The whole voting result comes inside a ajax response function $("a.vote").live('click',function() {} the function first evaluate error and give messages, if success, then, I can switch the class and print success message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole thing is easier if you don't use `vote-up-on` and `vote-down-on` as different class names. Just toggle one class `on`: http://jsfiddle.net/ghSEb/.

```
$(".vote").on("click", function() {
    $(".vote").not(this).removeClass("on");  // make sure to remove other vote
    $(this).toggleClass("on");​​​​​​​​​               // switch this one
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need to show initial vote value for users who has voted. If voted before, the user can see he voted up or down without clicking.

Comment: @Jenny: Just add the class `on` in HTML.

Comment: 1. add class "on" to up arrow or down arrow? 2. for a user has not voted, his arrows are both gray(off), can't make it initially "on".

Comment: @Jenny: To the arrow that represents the user's vote. The fiddle above has them both off; to have one on by default see http://jsfiddle.net/ghSEb/1/.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code on jsfiddle with my html, it works. But once I put it in my file, it doesn't response to click. Should I put your js inside my ajax response funtion, or I have to put it outside? I prefer to put it inside when get ajax response.

Comment: My best bet is to use it in `$(document).ready` and perhaps you need `$(document).on("click", ".vote", ...)`.

Comment: yes, if use it in $(document).ready  , it works perfectly. but the switch comes before ajax function validate the votes. is there a way I call this switching function inside the ajax response function?

Comment: @Jenny: You can of course put it in `success:` from `$.ajax` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use the condition inside of [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
var $voteDown = $("a.vote-up-down");
$(".vote-up-on").toggleClass('vote-up-off',$voteDown.hasClass("vote-up-off"))
$(".vote-up-off").toggleClass('vote-up-on',$voteDown.hasClass("vote-up-on"))
```